# How can I keep Android Studio from periodically freezing when editing a text file with 40k lines?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a Macbook Pro M2 Max with 96 gb of ram. So I can assign Android Studio whatever amount I want but I don't know which settings to modify.

My main issue is that I have a text file with ~40k lines. It isn't code, it is just a text file, but it is part of the project so I use Android Studio to edit it. Typically editing it means adding 3 or 4 new lines. While editing the file Android Studio will freeze for a few seconds.

Is there some setting I can change to allow it handle files that large?

Comment: Try IDE main menu `Help | Change Memory Settings` to use a large memory value. If it doesn't help, you could report this issue via `Help | Contact Support` with the log from `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data` attached.

Comment: I have edited that before but I don't know which of all the memory settings would affect this.

Comment: Try a large value like 5gb there. If it doesn't help, then I recommend you to contact the JetBrains support team via `Help | Contact Support` and they could help to investigate this issue better with the logs or other needed info.

Comment: Actually I'm already using 6gb there. I'll contact them.